# How to listen resize event of Stage in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, javafx-8, listener

I want to perform some functionality on resize event of form (or `Scene` or `Stage` whatever it is).

But how can I detect resize event of form in JavaFX?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can listen to the changes of the [`widthProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#widthProperty--) and the [`heightProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#heightProperty--) of the `Stage`:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
     // Do whatever you want
});

stage.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
     // Do whatever you want
});
```

---

**Note:** To listen to both width and height changes, the same listener can be used really simply:

```
ChangeListener<Number> stageSizeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    System.out.println("Height: " + stage.getHeight() + " Width: " + stage.getWidth());

stage.widthProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
stage.heightProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
```

Comment: I am trying to get the pane size on the stageSizeListener like proposed here. It works but with error. It seems that my pane size is resized after the stage listener is triggered. That inverts my size on fullscreen and reverse. Realy bad. If I resize slowlly it looks good, but it is not ok when I resize really fast.

Comment: This would invoke "Do whatever you want" two times, is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible to build a buffer of changes and process it only after a certain treshhold, the same way when you type into a text area and the change event is triggered only if you "stop" typing. It would be even quite simple to build a generic  DelayedChangeListener.

Comment: I can make this code work on the stage, but what I don't understand is how to catch it up the stack. Or even if you can. For example, if you detect the change on stage do I have to fire an event on the scene, and then up the stack? Assume Stage -> Scene -> vbox -> vbox2 -> node. How could I filter at vbox2 for the changes to stage?

Answer (score 3):

Keeping a fixed width to height ratio:

```
stage.minHeightProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty().multiply(0.5));
stage.maxHeightProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty().multiply(0.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut the long story short :

```
container.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if (newValue.floatValue()!=oldValue.floatValue()) resizeKids(newValue);
        }
    });
```

Also you may want to check new width/height with the old values for **prevent duplication**.