# Intercept window resize in the controller in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have this controller associated with an FXML:

```
public class MainController {

    private Stage stage;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
    }

    private Stage getStage() {
        stage = (Stage) mainPane.getScene().getWindow();
        return stage;
    }
}
```

I would need to intercept the window resizing event.

how can I do this in the controller?

Comment: What did you try? Did you Google at all?

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216268/how-to-listen-resize-event-of-stage-in-javafx ?

Comment: I had read that example, but it is not clear, as it does not explain how to use the code.
in fact, that code in the controller creates an error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this seems to work:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    mainPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observableScene, oldScene, newScene) -> {
        if (oldScene == null && newScene != null) {
            newScene.windowProperty().addListener((observableWindow, oldWindow, newWindow) -> {
                if (oldWindow == null && newWindow != null) {
                    getStage().widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                        System.out.println(newVal);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private Stage getStage() {
    stage = (Stage) mainPane.getScene().getWindow();
    return stage;
}
```

practically, there is a check if the scene is already set or not.
thanks bye!