# On Javafx, how do I keep the ratio of the window(entire stage) when I change its width or height by click-and-dragging?

Tags: java, javafx

To rephrase the question, I want to know the way to keep the entire stage's height;width ratio the same when I run the finished code and get the stage(think of a typical popup box made in Javafx), and then left-click on the edge of the popup box and change the width, I want the 'height' to be resized automatically real-time so that the 'ratio' of height:width is always the same no matter what.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216268/how-to-listen-resize-event-of-stage-in-javafx

Comment: Thanks for the link. but the content on the link does not specify(or explain for beginners) what the parameters obs, oldVal, newVal mean. if obs is the changing sizes of the width or height, should I use 'pane.getWidth()'? and what does 'oldVal' which is 'old value' actually mean?

Comment: You seem to be doing something above your JavaFX programming knowledge. Master beginner tutorial then move up from there. When a change happens in a change listener, the newVal is now the current value and the oldVal is the value before the change. What you want to do is set a ratio based on the newVal. For example, if the height of the stage changes, you would use the height's newVal plus your ratio to set the width.

Comment: Sedrick: I see. So I clearly understand what newVal is for now. but I'm still confused why I need an obs value(because it seems like oldVal and newVal are enough to do the job.)

Comment: If you try to do this without the obs value, you will see that your code is broken. You may not need to use it, but the `Java` developers put it in the code structure for the cases where it's needed. Just use what you need.

Comment: so what value should I put for obs? I assume it can't be a completely random value that pops up in my head.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Structure your code just like in the link. You only need to place your own code where it says `//do whatever`. Though, I suggest you use the second part of the answer. So your code should be inside where the `System.out.print()` is located. Look up some `JavaFX` `ChangeEvent` examples and tutorials.